# Unable to connect to WiFi in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

I'm using Acer Aspire 4752 and Ubuntu 14.04, I'm unable to connect to WiFi, it keeps on asking password, but not connecting to the network.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>